# #Define & lpCmdLine arguments

Tags: c++, string, arguments, command-line-arguments, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to define a string from startup arguments?

For example, I have this code in header file:

```
#define MsgBox "Hello there!"
```

How to make it so that the *#define* string comes from the command line arguments?

So if I would start my application like this: app.exe -Test! - the MsgBox would be defined as "Test!".

Sorry if this is a bad explanation but hopefully at least some of you understood. 
It is important to get the *#define MsgBox* from command line arguments, not from the program's entry point. All the code should be in the header file.

To be honest with you, I haven't tried *anything* because I have no idea where to start.

Comment: If you want to define a macro value from **compiler command line** then you should tell us which compiler you use. If you would like to define a macro from **executable command line** (!!!) then sorry you can't because macros are resolved only at compile time (OK, I suppose this is not your case...just to be clear!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible because `#define` is a preprocessor command. That is, you can think of it as a find and replace that takes place at **compile time**. (They can be used for other things, but crucially, it is evaluated at compile time).

Why not just use a variable? That way it is type safe as well.

Update: Using the define

Say you have stored the argument in some global `lpCmdLine`

Then your define becomes

```
#define MsgBox lpCmdLine
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do it quite weird way because the _#define MsgBox_ is used quite a lot in the source, and I wanted to change it from static string to 'modifiable' via lpCmdLine. And I am not very familiar with the source, because it has at least 15K lines and it's cross-platform, but thanks for telling me that it's not possible. Will mark as answered when I can. (~5min).

Comment: Well you don't need to loose the define, just define it as the variable you store it in (I'll update the answer to explain)

Comment: Before you edit, I'll post here quickly. Do you mean I would use arguments normally, but then just store the variable to a string, and _#define_ the MsgBox from the stored string? **Edit:** Yeah, like that. Thanks. Will try that now.

Comment: Remember `define`s are just find and replaces, so if you define as in the answer, everywhere there is the word `MsgBox`, at compile time, it will be replaced with `lpCmdLine` (which needs to be accessible to everywhere where the define is used, eg a global in a header that is always included, but it sounded like you were doing that anyway).

Comment: Yeah I got it working, I passed lpCmdLine arguments to the _#define_ and it works perfectly. :)